# Web configuration file being accessed in the wrong folder

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed an asp.net website on a production server. It is working on my local but on the server I get this error:

> An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start
>   monitoring changes to
>   'E:\HostingSpaces\xxxxx\xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com\wwwroot\admin\web.config'
>   because access is denied

This looks to me that the app is looking for the web.config in the admin folder while it is obviously in the root.
How is this possible? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS which is hosting ASP.NET is looking for a potential web.config file in every folder of your site, not just in the root folder.

This is because you may want to override certain settings for just one folder.

So you may have a web.config in `admin` but IIS hasn't got access to it, or IIS hasn't got access to the whole `admin` folder.

Check the permissions on that directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the directory it has been deployed to does not have the correct read/write permissions for IIS to read the web.config.

Each website configured in IIS 6+ runs under a specific AppPool. That app pool runs under a specific user account, and it is that user account that needs read/write permissions to this directory.